# Sub-Aggregation Issue When One Document

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm trying to do an aggregation over an array of items and I'm not getting the results I expect when the query I run matches only a single document. What I'm trying to do is aggregate based on `itemTypeName` and then sum up the `itemCount` for each such bucket.

Example record I'm trying to aggregate on:

```
"itemsSummed": [
                 {
                    "itemTypeID": 1,
                    "itemTypeName": "Widget",
                    "itemCount": 5
                 },
                 {
                    "itemTypeID": 3,
                    "itemTypeName": "FizzBuzz",
                    "itemCount": 1
                 }
              ]
```

Here's the mapping for the element:

```
"itemsSummed": {
                    "properties": {
                       "itemTypeID": {
                          "type": "long"
                       },
                       "itemTypeName": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "fields": {
                             "raw": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                             }
                          }
                       },
                       "itemCount": {
                          "type": "double"
                       }
                    }
                 }
```

Finally, here's the aggregation query I currently have:

```
"ByItemType": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "itemsSummed.itemTypeName.raw"
  },
  "aggs": {
    "SumItemCount": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "itemsSummed.itemCount"
      }
    }
  }
```

This returns the following result:

```
"ByItemType": {
     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
     "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": "Widget",
           "doc_count": 1,
           "SumItemCount": {
              "value": 6
           }
        },
        {
           "key": "FizzBuzz",
           "doc_count": 1,
           "SumItemCount": {
              "value": 6
           }
        }
     ]
  }
```

So the problem is that it is summing up both values for each bucket, instead of separating them. I'd expect a `SumItemCount` of 5 for "Widget" and 1 for "FizzBuzz".

I'm an ES novice, but my employer has a decent amount of experience with it and I know that previously we did use some nested properties but they were eventually ripped out due to other issues. We've also experimented with [aggregation pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html) but our results are the same.

How can we get this aggregation to work for single-document scenarios? Are we stuck putting back the nested properties?

Comment: The issue is not a single-document scenario as you say, in fact you'll get more weird results when you aggregate (on any property of `itemsSummed`) over many documents. You need to bring back the nested mapping for it. What were the 'other issues' due to which this was ripped off?

Comment: @VinuDominic thanks for confirming what we feared: the specific reasoning behind removing the nested properties has been forgotten by those involved, but we'll just add it back for this specific scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Nested datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) and [Nested Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) to make this work.

**New mapping with nested datatype:**

```
{
  "itemsSummed": {
    "type": "nested",                 <--- This line is the only change in mapping.
    "properties": {
      "itemTypeID": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "itemTypeName": {
        "type": "string",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      },
      "itemCount": {
        "type": "double"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Nested Aggregation:**

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "nestedAgg": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "itemsSummed"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ByItemType": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "itemsSummed.itemTypeName.raw"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "SumItemCount": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "itemsSummed.itemCount"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Response:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "nestedAgg": {
      "doc_count": 2,
      "ByItemType": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "FizzBuzz",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "SumItemCount": {
              "value": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Widget",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "SumItemCount": {
              "value": 5
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that is very helpful

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)